# Label cannot be used to last i.e. break for label in the front?

Tags: loops, perl

How come perl cannot last i.e. break for label in the front ahead ?
How should the correct syntax be ?

```
my $f;my $err=9;
my @l=(7,8,9,10);
for (@l) { 
  last T if $_==$err
}
$f=@l;
print "\ncomplete";
T:
print "\ncontain error";

Label not found for "last T" at ./non.pl line 17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `return` exits scopes until a sub call is found,
- `die` exits scopes until an `eval` is found, and
- `last`, `next` and `redo` exit scopes until a loop is found.

To jump ahead, use `goto`.

```perl
goto T if $_ == $err;
```

But wouldn't this be clearer:

```perl
my @l = ( 7, 8, 9, 10 );

my $err = 9;

my $f;
if ( grep { $_ == $err } @l ) {   # Or `first` from List::Util
   say "contain error";
   $f = undef;
} else {
   say "complete";
   $f = @l;
}
```

If you plan to check against the same `@l` many times, this would be better:

```perl
my @l = ( 7, 8, 9, 10 );
my %l = map { $_ => 1 } @l;

my $err = 9;

my $f;
if ( $l{ $err } ) {
   say "contain error";
   $f = undef;
} else {
   say "complete";
   $f = @l;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To use `last T`, you need to be inside of a loop with the label `T`.

To do what it looks like you want to do, the correct syntax is

```
goto T if $_==$err
```